# Can we run automated tests using flutter_driver on Firebase Test Lab?

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-test, firebase-test-lab

I am able to run automation tests on sample flutter application using flutter_driver on Android Emulator. I am looking for options of executing on Device Clouds. There are few threads which talk about executions on AWS Device Farm. However, I am interested in Firebase Test Lab. Similar to how we can execute automated scripts in SauceLabs, is there an option to run automated tests in Firebase Test Lab using flutter_driver?

Answer (score 2):

It's currently not possible.  Test Lab only supports testing Android apps with Espresso or UI Automator, and iOS apps with XCTest.  There is currently no other framework support.  As stated in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab):

> Test Lab runs Espresso and UI Automator 2.0 tests on Android apps, and XCTest tests on iOS apps. Write tests using one of those frameworks, then run them through the Firebase console or the gcloud command line interface.

Feel free to [file a feature request with Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support).

Comment: There's an open feature request for Flutter support on the [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/115927909).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of flutter_driver , use **[integration_test](https://pub.dev/packages/integration_test)** package

Tests written with the [integration_test](https://pub.dev/packages/integration_test) package can:

1- Run directly on the target device, allowing you to test on multiple Android or iOS devices using Firebase Test Lab.

2- Run using flutter_driver.

3- Use flutter_test APIs, making integration tests more like writing widget tests.

You can learn more about **Migrating from flutter_driver** **[here](https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/integration-tests#migrating-from-flutter_driver)** .

Comment: Yeah I did :) at the end I switched driver and target and it‘s working now. Thanks :)

Comment: @Rebar does it give you one video per test or one video with all tests mashed together?

Comment: One video with all tests together. I activated it for Pixel 2XL, Nexus 7 and Nexus 10