# Different possibilities of Firebase Test Labs for flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-test, firebase-test-lab

I have a flutter app developed and now I need to integrate automated UI testing, upon some research, I came to know about Firebase Test Lab (https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab)

Then I learned that it is not supported for Flutter (https://stackoverflow.com/a/61779777)

On further digging I found Flutter Test (https://flutter.dev/docs/testing) and to be specific I was in need of Integration Testing (https://flutter.dev/docs/testing#integration-tests), but the problem I see here is this integration testing can not be automated (using CI/CD or using other third party services) or I may be wrong in this understanding.

Hence I wanted to ask to the Flutter and Firebase community that

1. Is there any way I can use Test Labs of Firebase for Flutter Project
2. Or some other service provider where I can get near to similar service / functionality what Firebase Test labs offers for Android / iOS

Thanks.

Comment: Recommendations for off-site technologies or content are off-topic on Stack Overflow, so I'd recommend removing that second bullet and changing the title to prevent your question from getting closed.

Comment: On your first point, Test Lab still does not support Flutter as the other question you linked to already states.  You can always file a feature request with [Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support).

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen, I have tried to edit the question.

Comment: Sure @DougStevenson, will see if that helps.

Comment: So, is there any way I can achieve the same?, I am sure there would be many people who might be in need of this or already using it, which I am not aware of.